# Cuadro magico no guarda bien los valores

Tags: c++, c, dev-c++

Tengo que hacer un cuadro mágico, entonces la suma de las filas, las columnas y las diagonales debe ser la misma y el cuadro debe ser de n*n. Ya estuve intentando y... al parecer mi matriz no guarda bien los valores ya que solo guarda los últimos 3 valores ingresados, pero ya revise y según yo no tengo ningun error. ¿Me podrían ayudar?

Este es mi código:

```
/*
cuadroMagico.cpp
05/11/2021
Este programa te dice si un cuadro es magico o no
*/
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
//Declaracion e inicializacion de variables
int tam=0,suma=0,sumaC=0;
int arreglo[tam][tam];
int horizontal[tam],vertical[tam],diagonal1=0;

//Pedido del tamaño del cuadro
printf("Tamanio del lado del cuadro magico: ");
scanf("%d", &tam);

//LLenado de la matriz del cuadro magico
for(int i=0; i<tam; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<tam; j++){
        printf("Dame el valor de [%d][%d]: ",i,j);
        scanf("%d", &arreglo[i][j]);
    }
}

for(int i=0; i<tam; i++){   //Recorre filas
    suma = 0;
    sumaC = 0;
    for(int j=0; j<tam; j++){   //Recorre columnas  
        suma += arreglo[i][j];  //Suma de filas
        sumaC += arreglo[j][i]; //Suma de columnas
    }
    vertical[i] = suma; 
    horizontal[i] = sumaC;
    
    printf("H: %d ",horizontal[i]);
    printf("V: %d ",vertical[i]);
}

 for(int i=0; i<tam; ++i)
    diagonal1 += arreglo[i][i] + arreglo[i][tam-1-i];   //Suma de las diagonales
    
    printf("D: %d ",diagonal1);


//Impresion de la matriz
printf("\n\n");
for(int i=0; i<tam; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<tam; j++){
        printf("\t%d",arreglo[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

//Compara si es o no un cuadro magico
if(horizontal[0] == vertical[0] && vertical[0] == diagonal1)
        printf("\n\nSi es un cuadro mágico y la suma de cualquier fila, columna o diagonal es: %d", horizontal[0]);
    else
        printf("\n\nNo es un cuadro magico");

return 0;
}
```

[image: Esto es lo que me sale]

Comment: Estás inicializando el arreglo con tamaño 0. Mueve `int arreglo[tam][tam];` debajo de la línea `scanf("%d", &tam);`.

Comment: De hecho baja también la línea `int horizontal[tam],vertical[tam],diagonal1=0;` hacia después de `scanf("%d", &tam);`. Todo lo que use `tam` no puede declararse hasta luego de que el usuario ingrese el tamaño del arreglo.

Answer (score 3):

Para empezar, estás definiendo mal tu cuadrado:

```
int tam=0,suma=0,sumaC=0;
int arreglo[tam][tam];
```

Aún suponiendo que se pudiera definir una formación<sup>1</sup> usando **variables** para especificar su tamaño (spoiler: no se puede<sup>2</sup>), las formaciones no ajustan su tamaño *automágicamente* después de definirse:

```cpp
int tam=0,suma=0,sumaC=0;
int arreglo[tam][tam];                          // Tamaño es presuntamente cero
int horizontal[tam],vertical[tam],diagonal1=0;  // Tamaño es presuntamente cero

printf("Tamanio del lado del cuadro magico: ");
scanf("%d", &tam); // Aquí NO SE REAJUSTA EL TAMAÑO de 'arreglo', 'horizontal' o 'vertical'.
```

Si quieres una colección de datos cuyo tamaño se decida en tiempo de ejecución deberás usar memoria dinámica o contenedores, yo te aconsejo los segundos, por ejemplo:

```
using fila = std::vector<int>;
using tabla = std::vector<fila>;

int tamanyo;
std::cin >> tamanyo;

// Una tabla de 'tamanyo' filas y cada fila con 'tamanyo' columnas
tabla t = tabla(tamanyo, fila(tamanyo));
```

Para recoger datos de una tabla como la anterior basta con un bucle `for` de rango:

```
for (auto &f : t)
{
    for (auto &valor : f)
        std::cin >> valor;
}
```

---

###### <sup>1</sup>También conocida como *arreglo* o en inglés *array*.

###### <sup>2</sup>Eso es conocido como [*formaciones de tamaño variable*](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=c%2B%2B+vla) y no está permitido en C++ salvo usando extensiones de compilador.

Answer (score 2):

Tu código tiene 2 errores mayores:

## VLA con tamaño 0

El primero de ellos aqui:

```c
int tam=0,suma=0,sumaC=0;
int arreglo[tam][tam];
int horizontal[tam],vertical[tam],diagonal1=0;
```

`tam` es cero, y luego lo usas para darle tamaños a los arrays. C es bastante simple, el tamaño que le des inicialmente a esos arrays será el tamaño que tendrán durante el resto del programa. Estos no van observando la variable `tam` y cada que `tam` cambia ellos cambian su tamaño, ellos tienen un tamaño de `0` durante todo el programa.

De aquí surgen dos problemas.

##### Comportamiento indefinido

Según el estándar de C, si a un VLA (un array cuyo tamaño no se conoce en tiempo de compilación, como en este caso), les das un tamaño menor o igual a 0, el comportamiento es indefinido.

Que significa eso? Que cualquier cosa puede pasar. Es igual de valido que:

- Tu programa funcione
- Tu programa funcione a veces si a veces no
- Tu programa falle completamente
- Tu programa sea cerrado por el SO
- Tu programa [abra el navegador y te haga esto](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ).

En el momento en el que caes en comportamiento indefinido, tu programa ya no es valido.

##### Mas comportamiento indefinido

Supongamos que lo anteriormente mencionado fuera comportamiento definido. Supongamos que si le das un tamaño igual o menor a 0, el VLA tendrá un tamaño de 1 (Lo que puede ser que tu implementación haga, al final es comportamiento indefinido).

Si luego `tam` es, digamos por ejemplo, `3`, vas a acceder a los índices `0`, `1`, `2`, cuando solo el índice `0` es valido. Al leer y escribir en los índices `1` y `2` estarías interactuando con memoria que no tienes asignada para esa variable. Esto es otra vez comportamiento indefinido, y ya sabes lo que puede pasar.

Ahora, podemos usar algo de lógica aquí para entender porque es que:

> no guarda bien los valores ya que solo guarda los últimos 3 valores ingresados

Y es que la memoria de estas variables esta toda junta en el stack. Al escribir fuera del tamaño del array, probablemente estés sobrescribiendo las otras variables, llevando al comportamiento que indicas.

## Ambas diagonales en el mismo lugar

```c
for(int i=0; i<tam; ++i)
    diagonal1 += arreglo[i][i] + arreglo[i][tam-1-i];   //Suma de las diagonales
```

Estas sumando las 2 diagonales a `diagonal1`. O las separas en `diagonal1` y `diagonal2`, o cuando compares abajo en lugar de:

```c
vertical[0] == diagonal1
```

Tednrias que hacer:

```c
vertical[0] == (diagonal1/2)
```